# Selecting rows of a dataframe based on two conditions in Pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df, and I want to run something like:

```
subsetdf= df.loc[(df['Item_Desc'].str.contains('X')==True) or \
                 (df['Item_Desc'].str.contains('Y')==True ),:]
```

that selects all rows that have the Item Desc column a substring of "X" or "Y".

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I get the error when I run that.  Any help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `|` instead of `or`. So:

```
df.loc[(cond1) | (cond2), :]
```

The `or` operator wants to compare two boolean values (or two expression that evaluate to True or False). But a Series (or numpy array) does not simply evaluates to True or False, and in this case we want to compare both series element-wise. For this you can use `|` which is called 'bitwise or'.

Pandas follows here the numpy conventions. See [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#using-if-truth-statements-with-pandas) in the pandas docs for an explanation on it.

Comment: Would you mind pointing me to the docs for this?  Is this a pandas thing or a python thing?  I couldn't find anything about "|"

Comment: @joris, nice answer. Is there are more general way? e.g. if you have a list of column names e.g. `['d1', 'd2', 'd3' ...]` is there a way specifing a common condition to apply to all and include the row if any of them match.  In my case the cols d1 etc have either 1 or 0, and want only the rows with a 1 in any one of the cols d1 etc. There are other cols, with other data e.g. text, which I'm not considering for this selection

Comment: Not a general solution, but in that case you could do something like `(df[cols] == 1).any(axis=1)` to use as condition.

Answer (score 3):

The condition should be as follows

```
df.loc[(cond1) | (cond2)]
```

Each condition has to be enclosed in parentheses as well.  High priority is given for parentheses than the bitwise 'OR' operator.  When the parentheses are not provided it would also give the same error